# Употребление слова "рандеву"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Увидел в одном рассказе следующий оборот.

> Потом он проводил меня с работы домой, сопровождал во время вечерней пробежки, а когда я с приятелями отправился в рандеву по барам, дрон следовал за нами от одного заведения к другому.

Это корректное употребление слова "рандеву" или нет и почему? Я не смог нигде найти толкового объяснения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**...отправился в рандеву по барам...**

Скорее всего, это **неверное употребление слова**, даже если предположить его иронический смысл.

**РАНДЕВУ**, неизм.; ср. [франц. rendez-vous]. 1. Заранее условленное свидание (преимущественно любовное). Назначить р. **Пригласить на р.** кого-л. Любовное р. В четыре часа у меня р. в кафе. Р. не состоялось.

**РАНДЕВУ** — свидание, назначенная встреча (до реформы 1918 года в русском языке писалось как «рандэ-ву»).

В Нацорпусе  предлог В встречается только в одном примере (П.п.): **В "Рандеву" участвовали все звёзды цирка, эстрады, Игорь Тальков в том числе.** [И. Э. Кио. Иллюзии без иллюзий (1995-1999)]

Answer (score 0):

Если верить сайту Platforma, фраза принадлежит писателю, журналисту, сценаристу и редактору Антону Фридлянду (рассказ "[Дрон](http://projects.platfor.ma/dron-dron-dron/)"). Трудно заподозрить автора в отсутствии базовых знаний, скорее всего по ошибке кто-то перепутал два французских слова, *рандеву* и *вояж*. *Вояж по барам* звучало бы вполне корректно в этом месте.

Comment: Вы думаете, это редактор перепутал? Что-то сомнительно. Скорее автор сознательно  "расширяет" значение слова.

Comment: На каком основании? Просто захотелось - и расширяет?

Comment: Пусть было бы рандеву с приятелем в баре, но по барам?! Отправился в рандеву?!

Comment: Возможно, здесь метафора (метонимия), перенос по смежности, в том числе по логической смежности.  Рандеву (вояж,  путешествие) рассматривается  как ВСТРЕЧА с новыми людьми и впечатлениями.